# Log4j log files not created in android

Tags: android, log4j

I am using Log4j to log data in my android application. I have configured the log4j with the help of the following class, but the log files are not getting created.

console logging is enabled, maxfilesize and maxbackupsize are also good. please let me know what i am missing here.

```
public class ConfigureLog4J {

static LogConfigurator logConfigurator = new LogConfigurator();
private static final int maxFileSize = 1024 * 5; // 100KB
public static final int maxBackupSize = 2; // 2 backup files
public static final String LOG_FILE_NAME = "bitzer.log";

private static HashMap<Integer, Level> logLevelMap = new HashMap<Integer, Level>();

static {
    logLevelMap.put(0, Level.OFF);
    logLevelMap.put(1, Level.ERROR);
    logLevelMap.put(2, Level.INFO);
    logLevelMap.put(3, Level.WARN);
    logLevelMap.put(4, Level.DEBUG);
    logLevelMap.put(5, Level.ALL);
}

public static void startWithLogLevel(int logLevel) {

    logConfigurator.setFileName(getLogFileName());
    logConfigurator.setRootLevel(getLevelFromInt(logLevel));
    logConfigurator.setUseFileAppender(true);
    logConfigurator.setUseLogCatAppender(isConsoleLoggingEnabled());
    logConfigurator.setMaxFileSize(getMaxFileSize());
    logConfigurator.setMaxBackupSize(maxBackupSize);
    // Set log level of a specific logger
    // logConfigurator.setLevel("org.apache", Level.ERROR);
    logConfigurator.setResetConfiguration(true);
    logConfigurator.configure();
}

private static long getMaxFileSize() {
    return CompanySettings.getInstance().getValueAsInteger(R.string.max_log_size);
}

private static boolean isConsoleLoggingEnabled() {
    return CompanySettings.getInstance().getValueAsBoolean(R.string.consoleLoggingEnabled);
}



private static Level getLevelFromInt(int newLogLevel) {
    return logLevelMap.get(newLogLevel);
}

public static String getLogsDirectory() {
    if(AppData.getInstance().getContext()!=null)             
    { String packageName = AppData.getInstance().getContext().getPackageName();
        System.out.println("sundeep package name is not null and it's"+packageName);
    return "data/data/" + packageName + "/logs/";
    }
    return null;
}

public static String getLogFileName() {
    return getLogsDirectory() + LOG_FILE_NAME;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## SLF4J Overview

I highly recommend you use **[SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/android/)**, which is log4j's "older brother" of sorts; the same developers who made log4j made SLF4J to address the shortcomings of log4j.

The difference is, whereas log4j is a full-fledged logging framework, SLF4J is a facade which you use directly in your Java code. The facade aspect allows you to plugin a concrete logging implementation — such as log4j, logback, Android's `Log` utility, etc. — at runtime.

It allows you to write code that can be used between different projects without having to go through your code and convert your logging statements to use the target project's logging framework. If you have several thousand lines of code which use log4j, but the target you're importing them into uses Apache Commons logging, you'll soon find yourself with a headache if you manually make the changes... even with the assistance of a capable IDE.

### Using log4j in Android

There's a great Android library for logging to log4j — as well as many other logging frameworks as well — called **[android-logging-log4j](https://code.google.com/p/android-logging-log4j/)**. Check out the *[very excellent section on "**Using log4j over slf4j**"](https://code.google.com/p/android-logging-log4j/#Using_log4j_over_slf4j)*, which is the route I take in my Android projects.

---

## Examples from my own projects

Here are some examples from my own projects, such as my **[Awnry News & Weather app](http://naw.awnry.com)**. (Yeah, shameless plug :P)

### Required JARs on classpath

Basically these are the JARs I'll typically have in my project's classpath (version numbers vary as new releases come about, of course).

- `android-logging-log4j-1.0.3.jar`
- `log4j-1.2.17.jar`
- `slf4j-api-1.7.6.jar`
- `slf4j-log4j12-1.7.6.jar`

### Instantiating a class's logger

And here's how I instantiate my general logger in each of my classes that require logging:

```
package com.awnry.android.naw;
...
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
...
public class NawApplication extends Application
{
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(NawApplication.class);
```

As you can see, I'm only referencing SLF4J's [`Logger`](http://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/Logger.html) and [`LoggerFactory`](http://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/LoggerFactory.html) interfaces, even though the actual logging may eventually be accomplished using log4j or Android's `Log`.

***That's the beauty of SLF4J's facade design:*** You aren't tied down to any specific logging implementation/framework; you can change your mind in the future without having to change a line of your code. If you're using log4j over SLF4J now, but in the future you want to use the Apache Commons Logging framework all you have to do is switch out the SLF4J-to-log4j bridge to a SLF4J-to-ACL bridge, and none of your Java code will be any wiser as it only calls SLF4J *interfaces*. The time-honored adage to *code to an interface, not an implementation* holds true once again, and SLF4J is a superb example of that.

### Configuring the Android app's logging

In my [`Application.onCreate()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html#onCreate%28%29) method, I configure my logging like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    ...

    String logFile = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "logs" + File.separator + "debug.log";
    log.info("Application log file: " + logFile);

    LogConfigurator logConfigurator = new LogConfigurator(logFile, Level.TRACE);
    logConfigurator.configure();

    ...
}
```

This part is actually optional, I believe. In my case I do this because I use the **[ACRA library](http://acra.ch/)** to help catch unexpected program crashes and report the details back to me for debugging, so you might not need to define your android-logging-log4j's [`LogConfigurator`](https://code.google.com/p/android-logging-log4j/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/de/mindpipe/android/logging/log4j/LogConfigurator.java) as I do here.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are using log4j.
There are efficient Log utility is available specially designed for android.
Use LogCat. Its very simple to use and standard way of putting log in your android app.

Comment: `log4j` is **the** logging standard in Java. Plain and simple, period. Android's `Log` utility isn't. It's a nice utility, no doubt about that. But at the end of the day, you're going to run into instances where you need to use non-Android Java code from previous projects that used a different logging framework (most likely `log4j`). It's much easier to make multiple logging frameworks play nice with one another if you use a common facade in all of your code. I suggest using `SLF4J` so your existing Android code can continue using `Log` while you're non-Android code can use `log4j`, etc.

Comment: Hardik Trivedi, I accidentally downvoted, but it says I can't un-downvote until your post is edited. Sorry about that, I've been butter fingers all night. If you happen to edit your post, I'll undo my mistake. Sorry again. (Also, it won't let me use `@Hardik` for some reason, it removes the entire thing as if I didn't even type it. A StackExchange system bug maybe?)

Comment: @TheAwnryBear no problem buddy. I hv edited answer now